# How to redirect all www to non-www and SSL Url in Opencart?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, url, opencart

I am having problem with my opencart website while working with urls.

```
The problems are like - 
1. When I use http://example.com : It works fine.
2. When I use https://example.com : It works fine with my non-www ssl certificate
3. When I use http://www.example.com : I lose my styles.
4. When I use https://www.example.com : I lose my styles and works as secured page

Now I want it in these ways :
1. When I use http://example.com : It should redirect to https://example.com
2. When I use http://www.example.com : It should redirect to http://example.com so that I can't lose styles.
3. When I use www.example.com : It should redirect to https://example.com
4. When I use only example.com : It should redirect to https://example.com
```

Here is my current .htaccess.txt

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Please direct me how I can achieve what I want and how to fix styles problem.
Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (replacing the last three lines of the .htaccess file):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/checkout/?.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://url.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And make sure your opencart SSL settings are turned on with correct https:// URL in place.

And if the solution above does not work you can simply redirect all calls of www to non-www url where your website works perfectly with both SSL and styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my solution. He works in 2020.

```
# Redirect to non-www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mystore\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://mystore.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```